# How to fix 'vshost32.exe has stopped working' when calling the ShowDialog of OpenFileDialog?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm making a simple project in Visual Basic 2010 Express where I upload a photo and it calls for the ShowDialog of OpenFileDialog. If I make that specific form the start up form, It works fine. But if I start somewhere else, I get the error "vshost32.exe has stopped working". I also tried to trigger the function somewhere else but it seems that if two forms are active, the error shows. I tested other projects as well with the same function and all of them works.

Here's a list of things I have tried:

Unchecked the 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process'

Checked 'Enable ClickOnce security settings

Running VB 2010 as administrator

Made a new project and copied everything

Restarted my laptop

Here is the function which I just copied somewhere here:

```
Function UploadPhoto()
    Try
        Using openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\Pictures"
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEGs|*.jpg|GIFs|*.gif|Bitmaps|*.bmp|PNGs|*.png|AllFiles|*.*"
            If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then Exit Function

            If openFileDialog1.FileName.Length = 0 Then

            Else
                imgpath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                Try
                    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                    If Not IsNothing(picItem.Image) Then picItem.Image.Dispose() 
                    picItem.Image = bmp
                Catch
                    MsgBox("Not a valid image file.")
                End Try
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString & vbCrLf & ex.Message.ToString & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace.ToString)
    End Try
End Function
```

Later, I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling VB 2010

Comment: Try to update your framework on developing PC/machine in .NET 4.0 or above

Comment: Undiagnosable crashes of ShowDialog() are not uncommon.  You can only see *something* if you enable unmanaged debugging.  That's still a long way from fixing the kind of problem that a mis-behaving shell extension can cause.  Reinstalling the framework or VS won't do anything useful.  Use SysInternals' Autoruns utility to disable them one by one, starting with the ones not provided by Microsoft.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj I already have .NET 4.0 installed

Comment: Try to disable vshost (as I describe in the answer below) and re-try to debug your application directly the label is ("Activate the visual studio hosting process") or something like this in english :)

Comment: Another thing might do is: If your application “CPU destination” is “Any CPU” check the tick “Prefer 32 bit” Or change building destination in 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Ok try another way,

1 -Delete both obj and bin folder

2 -After that as you now seems are debugging under visual studio host (vshost.exe)  sandbox.
Try to debug your application directly (like in the image below seen).

[image]